# Trying to align my Hamburger Icon for mobile on the left

Tags: html

My navbar looks fine and it's responsive, however, for the mobile view, I'm not able to place the hamburger Icon on the left. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8f1a3.png)

```
<!-- NavBar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light sticky-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row w-100">
                    <a class="navbar-brand align-items-end" href="#">Labor IN-Sight</a>
                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav align-items-end ml-auto">
                            <li class="navbar-item active">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#" anchor="Home">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                            <li class="navbar-item text-nowrap">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#" anchor="Benefits">Benefits</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="navbar-item text-nowrap">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#" anchor="Add-ons">Add-ons</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="navbar-item text-nowrap">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#" anchor="industries">Industries</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <form class="form-inline">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#contactexpert">Get Started</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

css
.navbar-brand {
    float: left;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 40px;
    height: 50px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-nav > li > a {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to align my hamburger icon on the left for the mobile version. I've tried to re-position it much time but nothing is working so far.

Comment: can you please share the screenshots? I am unable to see proper HTML from given code.

Comment: I,ve added the picture, if it's also possible to know how I can move the button on the right as well.

Comment: can you please share the pic of your requirement?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `float: left` on the `.navbar-brand` element when you'd want to set it on `.navbar-toggler` instead.

```
.navbar-toggler {
  float: left;
}
```

It would be even better to not use a float-based layouts anymore at all, but rather switch to a layout system based on `flexbox` or `grid`.

```css
.navbar-brand {
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 40px;
  height: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.navbar-toggler {
  float: left;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-nav>li>a {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light sticky-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row w-100">
      <a class="navbar-brand align-items-end" href="#">Labor IN-Sight</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav align-items-end ml-auto">
          <li class="navbar-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#" anchor="Home">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            <li class="navbar-item text-nowrap">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#" anchor="Benefits">Benefits</a>
            </li>
            <li class="navbar-item text-nowrap">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#" anchor="Add-ons">Add-ons</a>
            </li>
            <li class="navbar-item text-nowrap">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#" anchor="industries">Industries</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#contactexpert">Get Started</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

It might even be simpler to just rearrange the markup and switch the two elements, but it's hard to tell how that might influence the rest of your page, having only the snippet you posted to go on.

```css
.navbar-brand {
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 40px;
  height: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-nav>li>a {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light sticky-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row w-100">
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand align-items-end" href="#">Labor IN-Sight</a>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav align-items-end ml-auto">
          <li class="navbar-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#" anchor="Home">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            <li class="navbar-item text-nowrap">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#" anchor="Benefits">Benefits</a>
            </li>
            <li class="navbar-item text-nowrap">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#" anchor="Add-ons">Add-ons</a>
            </li>
            <li class="navbar-item text-nowrap">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#" anchor="industries">Industries</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#contactexpert">Get Started</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can encapsulate Navbar button and `.navbar-brand` anchor tag in a `div`. After that for mobile devices, in your case `@media (max-width: 768px)`, set `display: flex` with `flex-direction: row-reverse`.

Below is the sample code:

```css
.navbar-brand {
    float: left;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 40px;
    height: 50px;
    font-weight: bold;
}


@media (max-width: 768px) {
      .test {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row-reverse;
    }  
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-nav > li > a {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- NavBar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light sticky-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row w-100">
            <div class="test">
                    <a class="navbar-brand align-items-end" href="#">Labor IN-Sight</a>
                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav align-items-end ml-auto">
                            <li class="navbar-item active">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#" anchor="Home">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                            <li class="navbar-item text-nowrap">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#" anchor="Benefits">Benefits</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="navbar-item text-nowrap">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#" anchor="Add-ons">Add-ons</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="navbar-item text-nowrap">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#" anchor="industries">Industries</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <form class="form-inline">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#contactexpert">Get Started</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </nav>  
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```